# Footer with "bottom:0" CSS attribute

Tags: html, css

I have difficulties sticking a footer at the end of each pages without showing a bottom margin on very big resolutions (2560x1440 for instance).

When used as "position:absolute" element it works fine on small heights pages such as http://www.perfect-profile.fr/mesdames
Unfortunately, when on big heights pages, the footer will stays in the middle of the page : http://www.perfect-profile.fr/prix

I tried "position:relative" and that's the opposite : it show at the end of the content on big heights pages and keeps a margin in the bottom on small heights pages. I could determine a section min-height but the result would be hasardous on big resolutions.

Do you have any clue what I could do ? Thanks

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: Thanks but I already tried display:flex and it doesn't work at all in this case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
position:fixed
```

and your footer will stay at the bottom of the viewport...

Comment: I don't want it to be fixed on the bottom of the viewport. I need it right at the end of the content.

Comment: Well then take away all of the positioning, and let the footer just be part of the normal document flow....

Answer (score -1):

Well, as it seemed trickier than expected I had no other choice than to rethink the display.

I used a "position:fixed" and "bottom:0" footer to put it at the very bottom of the viewport no matter how much content the pages have. Not what the client expected but that does the trick.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me on this one. Problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

```
<style>
footer
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
}
</style>
```

you have to set footer position fixed or absolute

Comment: did you set the position of footer

Comment: Yes. 

footer {    background-color: #000 !important; padding-top: 10px; position: absolute !important; margin-top: 20px; bottom: 0; }

Plus this Bootstrap class : .col-xs-12 {    width: 100%; }

I tried to put width:100% directly to footer element to be sure and it didn't work either.